# How can I receive Genicam packets from a device in a docker container?

Tags: computer-vision

I installed a command line tool which accepts genicam packets from a device as input into a docker image. If I use the option `--network host` in the `run` command for the container the packets are received. If I use `-p 3956:3956/udp` to expose the Genicam default port `3956` (e.g. stated here: [RoboRealm - GenICam - Instructions](http://www.roborealm.com/help/GenICam.php)) in the `run` command of the container I don't get packets. What did I wrong? Could the port be different from the default? How could I get the changed port then?

Comment: I am trying to adapt this solution for Basler cameras, which rely on the Genicam standard. Has anyone experience with that? I tried to adapt the compose config with no result as per today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plug and play solution in docker compose for it, however please check your container for vulnerabilities. If you do not use docker networks you can use network mode host instead.

````yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  your_container:
    image: your_image
    container_name: your_container
    #network_mode: host
    networks:
     - camera_vlan

networks:
  camera_vlan:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp2s0 # your adapter name goes here
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "your.device.ip.goes/here"
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Because Genicam will actually use another 2 random ports to establish the connection. You are supposed to be able to force those to a specific value but that's not well documented.
The way I tried to solve it was by creating a macvlan network.
https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/

If you are networking with unfamiliar protocols Wireshark is always a good place to start. It lets you see every single packet that passes in/out/between your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by [@Gornoka](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/22460/31879) works well. There is no need to add UDP port to detect the Genicam GigE camera. If multiple networks are to be used, something like below can be used

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  some_net:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
  camera_vlan:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp4s0 # adapter name changes as per deployment computer
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.3.0/24  
services:        
  some_service:
    image: image_name
    networks:
      some_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.8
      camera_vlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.3.150
```

It might be worth specifying a static ip-address to the camera_vlan network so that there is no ip-address conflict with other devices on the network.